# Wrapping a DIV around content and keeping it centered

Tags: html, css

I have a problem concerning CSS and HTML.

I'm trying to wrap a DIV around another element (an UL in this case) and having it wrap around it and at the same time keeping both centered. As an added bonus I can't set a specific width since the width of the content inside the wrapping DIV have to be dynamic (since this is basically a template).

I've tried floating, and that works as far as wrapping goes, but then the thing ends up either to the right or to the left.

I'm going a bit crazy over this, and google is no help!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Sorry about not including code or images. This is what I'm trying to do illustrated with images:

[One state of the UL width](http://sandbox.auforia.com/misc/help1.png)

[Another state of the width](http://sandbox.auforia.com/misc/help2.png)

The wrapping DIV *can't* stretch the full width of the container. It has to wrap *around* the UL.

The dark grey is the DIV around the UL. I need the DIV to wrap around the UL (which has a horizontal layout) no matter the width of the content, since like I said above, the content of the UL is going to by different from time to time. The text in the LIs are going to change.

I also need it to be centered. I've made it work with float left and float right, but I need it to be *centered*.

This is the code I'm currently using for the container DIV and the UL and LI elements:

```
#container{
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #grey;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#container ul{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#container li{
    background: url(checkmark.png) center left no-repeat;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#container li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your current code and perhaps an idea of what you are expecting it to look like - perhaps a picture of a sample HTML layout ?

Comment: what @ManseUK said, or even better a jsFiddle.

Comment: You can use `margin: 0 auto;` for this. Give it as a CSS paramater to the wrapper div. This automaticallycenter the div (horizontally)

Comment: If your UL doesn't have an actual set width (set in the CSS or set dynamically) then it will take up the full width of its parent element even with "margin:0 auto;"

Comment: I can't set a specific width, so margin: 0 auto; is no good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I got it. Is it this you were looking for?? http://jsfiddle.net/vZNLJ/20/

```css
#wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto; /* to make the div center align to the browser */
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px; /* set it to anything */
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper ul {
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#wrapper ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
#wrapper ul li:last-child {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works if I set a specific width, which I can't.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm after. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post, but what you can do now is:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="button" value="Example Button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't wrapping the DIV around the content, but getting the content to state it's actual size, therefore pushing the DIV boundaries out.  There are several things that need to be considered when tackling this issue.  Not just from an existing UL or LI tag, but a DIV within a DIV.

I use custom tags to help describe layouts cleaner. Custom tags are DIV tags, thus their properties must be manipulated by CSS in order to get the proper behavior.

```
<layout-linear horizontal>
    <control-label>Label 1</control-label>
    <control-label>Label 2</control-label>
    <control-label>Label 3</control-label>
    <control-label>Label 4</control-label>
    <control-label>Label 5</control-label>
</layout-linear>
```

This layout suggests that the contents .. the control-label(s) tags .. will be display in a horizontal row.  To get the border for the layout-linear tag to wrap around the content of the control-label tags, there are several things to do:

```
layout-linear[horizontal]
{
    display : block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border : 1px solid black;
    padding : 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width : 100%;
    clear : both;
    text-align : center;
}
```

First, the box-sizing property must be set to border-box.  This will force the linear-layout (DIV) tag to wrap around content.  Padding, Border, Margin will insure that an empty DIV tag displays.  Other tricks to make an empty DIV tag display are to use   or :after { content:.; visibility: hidden; }.

If you don't want the control-label tags to wrap, adding white-space : nowrap.

I will discuss text-align when I discuss the float property of the control-label tag.

The next part requires the inner DIV tags (control-labels) to properly specify their box-sizing type and borders.

```
control-label
{
    display : inline-block;
    /* float : left; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border : 1px solid black;
    margin : 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding : 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Display : inline-block, causes the control-label tags to flow left to right.  Display : Block, will cause the tags to stack up vertically.

Float is commented out specifically to draw your attention to the fact that float will cause the layout-linear tag shrink to its smallest box size, based on the margins, padding, and border.

To have the control-labels flow right to left, add text-align : right to the layout-linear tag.  Or in this specific case, set text-align : center.

Again, box-sizing is used to tell the control-label (DIV) tag to wrap around it's content completely.  Not just the text, but the edges of the box as drawn by the border, padding and margin settings.

This arrangement of CSS properties is what causes the outer and inner boxes to be rendered properly, or as expected.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply code, but take a look at this fiddle I just setup, which might help:

http://jsfiddle.net/qXDJr/

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding what you mean. Example code will always help for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't work as I can't set a specific width, it has to be dynamic (based on the length of the text in the LIs) like it is when you set float left/right.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. 
If you cant set the width you can just add `align='center'` in the `div` wrapping `ul`

```
<div align="center">
<ul>
    <li>MenuItem</li>
    <li>MenuItem</li>
    <li>MenuItem</li>
</ul>
</div>
```